# Uploading file using OneDrive API

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am using MicrosoftGraph API and createUploadSession to upload file but it is throwing the following error.

`{ "error": { "code": "accessDenied", "message": "Access denied", "innerError": { "date": "2023-08-04T10:15:48", "request-id": "97676563-7d6e-4bb9-abd2-46513e0940b8", "client-request-id": "97676563-7d6e-4bb9-abd2-46513e0940b8" } } }`

Although I am able to create folders but still it's failing when uploading a file. I have these following permission :-

[permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owu6z.png)

Tried adding sharePoint permissions but still this issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

The error message "Access denied" indicates that the current user or application does not have the necessary permissions to perform the upload operation using the Microsoft Graph API

Did you do this after you added the permissions?

[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvZc5.png)

Here is test:
get token
[get token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l935x.png)

createUploadSession:
We need to get token to join Authorization
Authorization + token
[createUploadSession](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBKhH.png)

Comment: I tried that but the error is still the same.

Comment: Any other walkarounds?

Comment: Hi  I did a test with postman for your reference, I will update my answer later

Comment: Now It is throwing this error - {"error":{"code":"invalidRequest","message":"The Content-Range header is missing or malformed."}}